# JSTL calculation error

Tags: jstl

Is this the correct code to print out the calculated value? There seems to be no error but it just directly prints out all my values with the addition, times sign etc.

This is the code:

```
Monthly Instalment = <c:out value="(${LoanAmount} + (${LoanAmount} * ${IR} * ${param.loanPeriod}))/ (${param.loanPeriod} * 12)" />
```

Comment: For formatting code see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the entire calculation in `${...}` rather than just the individual variables:

```
Monthly Instalment = <c:out value="${(LoanAmount + (LoanAmount * IR * param.loanPeriod))/ (param.loanPeriod * 12)}" />
```

This causes the entire expression to be evaluated, whereas in your case each occurrence of `${...}` being evaluated individually and the result inserted into a string.

Answer (score 0):

One cause of that problem is not importing the JSTL library. Try putting

`<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld" prefix="c" %>`

...at the top of the JSP file.

Comment: I can try. Did the above help?

Comment: Nope. i already have the c tag library. there seems to be something wrong with the sentence itself